# Fast query on the number of elements in a quarter plane

Tags: algorithms

I have a scatter of 2D elements on a 2D plane.

I would like an efficient algorithm to prepare and query the number of points in a quarter plane (inclusive of boundary).

The quarter plane is defined by a point $(x,y)$. All elements $(x', y')$ where $x<=x'$ and $y<=y'$ are in the quarter plane.

For example

- I have elements `[(1,1), (2,2), (1,2), (3,2)]`,
- My queries are `[(1,1), (2,2), (3,3)]`

The program should return `[1,3,4]`.

This is for a past competitive programming challenge (WiFi Network problem in this [competition](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wXZ8DmW0MQ2aUoIo9Y5YCl-ec0ux2x4q/view))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 2D [Fenwick tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenwick_tree) can solve this in $O(\log^2 N)$ time and $O(N^2)$ space for both update and query, when your coordinates are integers and $N$ is the size of the maximum coordinate.

Fenwick trees are nice for competitive programming because they have a really compact implementation, for example in C++:

```
typedef unsigned long long uw;
uw lsb(uw x) { return x & -x; }
uw  up(uw x) { return x + lsb(x); }
uw  dn(uw x) { return x - lsb(x); }

template<class T> struct Fenwick2D {
  uw n; std::vector<std::vector<T>> b;
  Fenwick2D(uw n) : n(n), b(n+1, std::vector<T>(n+1)) { }

  void increase(uw x, uw y_, T v) {
    for (; x <= n; x = up(x))
      for (uw y = y_; y <= n; y = up(y))
        b[x][y] += v;
  }

  T prefix_sum(uw x, uw y_) {
    T s = 0;
    for (; x >= 1; x = dn(x))
      for (uw y = y_; y >= 1; y = dn(y))
        s += b[x][y];
    return s;
  }
};
```

And this shows your example from the question:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Fenwick2D<int> fw(4);
    fw.increase(1, 1, 1);
    fw.increase(2, 2, 1);
    fw.increase(1, 2, 1);
    fw.increase(3, 2, 1);
    std::cout << fw.prefix_sum(1, 1) << "\n";
    std::cout << fw.prefix_sum(2, 2) << "\n";
    std::cout << fw.prefix_sum(3, 3) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

This data structure is more general than your problem as well. In general it can increase any grid element $g_{x,y}$ by value $v$ (which decreases for negative $v$), and ask the value of the lower quadrant prefix sum $\sum_{i\leq x}\sum_{j\leq y} g_{i,j}$ for any $x, y$. Note that this means you can get area sums as well using 4 queries by the inclusion-exclusion principle.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. $O(N^2)$ space requirement is likely to make me run out of memory, is there a better solution?

Comment: @HKTong I would suggest asking a new question with any memory limits in mind. In general I believe you should ask a new question because I took a look at the programming problem and it involves circular neighborhood searches, which is different than what you asked here.